# Trouble with Laravel one-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I'm stuck on a Laravel one-to-many relationship that seems like it should be straightforward. I must be misunderstanding something:

My tables:

Invoices (belongs to contractor) (belongs to customer)

- id
- contractor_id
- customer_id
- other_columns

Customers (belongs to contractor) (has many invoices)

- id
- contractor_id
- other_columns

Contractor (has many invoices) (has many customers)

- id
- other_columns

I am trying to list all invoices with the name of the customer that it belongs to.

To do this, i set up the eloquent relationships inside the models like this:

```
protected $table = 'customers';

public function contractor() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Contractor', 'contractor_id');
}

public function invoices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Invoice');
}
```

Relationships are set up for contractor and invoice too.

I pass the variables into my view and then try to iterate through:

```
  @foreach($estimates as $estimate)
  <tr>
   <td>
      <h4><strong>{{$estimate->title}}</strong></h4>
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-usd text-info"></i> {{$estimate->total}}<br>
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user text-danger"></i> {{$estimate->customer->name}} <br>
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone text-info"></i> {{$estimate->phone}}
   </td>
  </tr>
   @endforeach
```

The error I am getting is: "trying to get property of non-object" on the line that has {{$estimate->customer->name}}

Seems like this should work, because the invoice model "belongsTo" the customer model in eloquent.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show us the code where `$estimates` gets loaded from the db?

Comment: First - do you have that relationship `belongsTo` setup on the `Invoice` model? Then - error says that `->customer` is `null`, so either no relationship is defined or it is, but there is no related model.